# combine rows in pandas after explode

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, explode

I have collected the data from twitter. I have miltiple columns but have an issue with one of them:

```
tweets_data['Mentioned Users']

0        [{'username': 'HuntTerrorist', 'displayname': ...
1        [{'username': 'AttorneyCrump', 'displayname': ...
2                                                     None
3        [{'username': 'realDonaldTrump', 'displayname'...
4                                                     None
                               ...                        
19995                                                 None
19996                                                 None
19997                                                 None
19998                                                 None
19999                                                 None
Name: Mentioned Users, Length: 20000, dtype: object
```

I want to get usernames from each row and place them back into dataframe.

I have tried the explode command:

```
exploded_df = tweets_data.explode('Mentioned Users')
user_df = exploded_df['Mentioned Users'].apply(pd.Series)
user_df['username']

0        HuntTerrorist
0          stinkytcat1
0           Nexussfire
0             BBCWorld
1        AttorneyCrump
             ...      
19995              NaN
19996              NaN
19997              NaN
19998              NaN
19999              NaN
Name: username, Length: 24886, dtype: object
```

The problem with this code is that it prints each mentioned user in a different row that extended the number of total rows. I am not able to add this column to the original one because of different length. So I want all usernames with index 0 to be in the same row (because they all in the same tweet).

Is there any way to combine the usernames or any alternative method o do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `exploding`, why dont you index the required column from the dictionary directly like below.

```
df['Required column']=dictionary['required column']
```